# "page"/create is colliding because slug django

Tags: python, django

I'm making Blog app.

The create blog page is `blog/create/` and the detail of blog is `blog/{slug}`. The slug does successfully show the page, but the create page is not showing because the word `create` is read as a slug by django.

The point is , how to filter the "blog/create/" and "blog/{slug}/" ?

This is my **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name="index"),
    path('<slug>/',views.show,name="show"),
    path('create/',views.create, name="create"),
]
```

Comment: Change the order of the patterns?

Comment: oh i get it , create first, and then slug?

Comment: You really Help Me Tonight :D, Thank You Sir